# Google map custom marker stays in wrong place

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker

I'm using google maps marker `iconView` property to show a custom marker, but the marker stays in the wrong place as you can see (the blue point is the google marker and it is in right place):

[image]

What I did try:

```swift
if let loc = map.myLocation {
    currentLocationMarker = GMSMarker()
    currentLocationMarker.iconView = UserLocation.fromNib()
    currentLocationMarker.map = map
    currentLocationMarker.position = loc.coordinate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `groundAnchor` property of `GMSMarker` we can change the draw position of marker :

```
marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```